# Style for every nth div with active class

Tags: jquery

In the code snippet you can toggle menu's by clicking the associated inputs (connected using `data-id`) but I want to be able to use CSS to style the `.menu__wrap` `background` of every other `active` menu in order to add differentiation between the active menu's.

So instead of applying some CSS like `.menu__wrap:nth-child(2)` to every other menu in the list, it only applies to the menu's with the `active` class.

In the snippet if two menu's are toggled, the second would get the style, and if all three are open, the middle menu would get the style. It would be every other `active` `.menu__wrap` gets the style.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="menu"]').change(function() {
    $(".menu[data-id=" + this.id + "]").toggleClass("active", this.checked);
    $(".menu__wrap[data-id=" + this.id + "]").toggleClass(
      "active",
      this.checked
    );
    if (
      $(this)
      .closest('[class*="list-"]')
      .is(".list-custom")
    ) {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this)
          .closest(".launch-icon")
          .addClass("checked");
        $(this)
          .closest(".list-custom")
          .addClass("checked");
      } else {
        $(this)
          .closest(".launch-icon")
          .removeClass("checked");
        $(this)
          .closest(".list-custom")
          .removeClass("checked");
      }
    }
  });
  $('input[name="menu"]').change();
});
```

```css
.menu {
  border: 2px solid;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.25s ease, visibility 0.25s ease, opacity 0.25s ease;
}

.menu__wrap {
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.menu.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: max-height 1.5s ease;
  max-height: 1000px;
}

.menu__wrap.active {
  transition: transform 0.25s ease;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.blue {
  background: blue
}

.green {
  background: green
}

.red {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-custom">
  <label for="a" class="launch-icon">
    Btn A
        <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="a">
 </label>
  <div class="indicator--inputs buttons"></div>
</div>
<div class="list-custom">
  <label for="b" class="launch-icon">
    Btn B
        <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="b">
 </label>
  <div class="indicator--inputs buttons"></div>
</div>
<div class="list-custom">
  <label for="c" class="launch-icon">
    Btn C
        <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="c">
 </label>
  <div class="indicator--inputs buttons"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="list">
  <div data-id="a" class="menu">
    <div data-id="a" class="menu__wrap">
      <div class="box blue"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-id="b" class="menu">
    <div data-id="b" class="menu__wrap">
      <div class="box green"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-id="c" class="menu">
    <div data-id="c" class="menu__wrap">
      <div class="box red"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `change` event handler, you can iterate over each of the menus that have the `active` class and highlight every second one (based on the index being odd) using code similar to this (where I've misappropriated your `blue` class):

```
$('.menu.active').each(function (i) {
  $(this).removeClass('blue');
  if (i % 2 == 1) $(this).addClass('blue');
});
```

Full code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="menu"]').change(function() {
    $(".menu[data-id=" + this.id + "]").toggleClass("active", this.checked);
    $(".menu__wrap[data-id=" + this.id + "]").toggleClass(
      "active",
      this.checked
    );
    $('.menu.active').each(function (i) {
      $(this).removeClass('blue');
      if (i % 2 == 1) $(this).addClass('blue');
    });
    if (
      $(this)
      .closest('[class*="list-"]')
      .is(".list-custom")
    ) {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this)
          .closest(".launch-icon")
          .addClass("checked");
        $(this)
          .closest(".list-custom")
          .addClass("checked");
      } else {
        $(this)
          .closest(".launch-icon")
          .removeClass("checked");
        $(this)
          .closest(".list-custom")
          .removeClass("checked");
      }
    }
  });
  $('input[name="menu"]').change();
});
```

```css
.menu {
  border: 2px solid;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.25s ease, visibility 0.25s ease, opacity 0.25s ease;
}

.menu__wrap {
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.menu.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: max-height 1.5s ease;
  max-height: 1000px;
}

.menu__wrap.active {
  transition: transform 0.25s ease;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.blue {
  background: blue
}

.green {
  background: green
}

.red {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-custom">
  <label for="a" class="launch-icon">
    Btn A
        <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="a">
 </label>
  <div class="indicator--inputs buttons"></div>
</div>
<div class="list-custom">
  <label for="b" class="launch-icon">
    Btn B
        <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="b">
 </label>
  <div class="indicator--inputs buttons"></div>
</div>
<div class="list-custom">
  <label for="c" class="launch-icon">
    Btn C
        <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="c">
 </label>
  <div class="indicator--inputs buttons"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="list">
  <div data-id="a" class="menu">
    <div data-id="a" class="menu__wrap">
      <div class="box blue"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-id="b" class="menu">
    <div data-id="b" class="menu__wrap">
      <div class="box green"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-id="c" class="menu">
    <div data-id="c" class="menu__wrap">
      <div class="box red"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How would I change the code if I wanted to add a separate class when all three menu's are `active` but to only the second active menu in the list. I tried if `(i == 3 && i % 2 == 1)` assuming i==3 means if 3 menu's are active.

Comment: @KyleUnderhill in the `.each` function `i` will never get to 3 as there are 3 menus which will have indexes 0, 1 and 2. You can check the number of active menus using `.length` and use that to add another class e.g. `if (i % 2 == 1) { $(this).addClass('blue'); if ($('.menu.active').length == 3) $(this).addClass('anotherclass'); }`